# Which communications satellite "fell down?"

Tags: artificial-satellite, testing, failure

I remember reading about an accident where a big, expensive communications satellite actually fell off it's mount and landed on the floor of the room where it was undergoing final assembly and preparation (I believe). It was supported on a tilting mount, and it was raised up without the mounting bolts having being in place.

The time frame is roughly two years ago (~2013 to 2015).

Recently I searched for the news again, and I can't find a trace of it on the internet!

Payloads are built to endure serious vibration and shock in order to reliably survive launch with a wide safety margin. However, when a rigid object without "crush zones" or shock absorbers falls and lands on a hard surface, accelerations can be 100's or 1000's of gees for milliseconds.

Any idea which satellite it was? A link would be great.

The idea is that even in the 21st century, rigid adherence to detailed written procedures as well as *writing those detailed procedures* are still both *really important*!

Comment: I'm sure it's the linked story. It's existence goes in waves, but still, I bet that's it.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Thanks - yep that's it! It's one of those images that - once you see it - can never be un-seen. I'll do my "due diligence" next time.

Comment: No worries. It took a fair bit of work for me to find the question actually, I had the advantage of remembering it be asked.