# First use of spacecraft thermal control louvers, doors, pinwheels, or other things that physically actuate either passively or actively?

Tags: history, spaceflight-firsts, thermal, thermal-control

Below are some examples of

**Question:** What was the first use of spacecraft thermal control louvers, doors, pinwheels, or other things that physically actuate either passively or actively?

---

From [this answer to *What are the louver-like structures on the sides of the Mariner 4 probe?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30380/12102)

> I just ran across the louvers in close-up view!
>
> In the JLP video [1965: Discovery at Mars](https://youtu.be/q5dzDWjN7Z4) there is an excellent video *The Changing Face of Mars* with introductory remarks by its producer/director/writer, Blaine Baggett, Director, Office of Communication and Education, JPL, about Mariner 3 and 4 missions to Mars embedded within his Von Karman lecture.
>
> At about `00:38:50` you can see them "moving" (could be Mariner 3 or 4):
>
> [image: Mariner 4 thermal louvers]

From [What are these air-vent-like structures on this satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15306/12102)

> I struck out with my [previous question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15300/12102) so I'll try again.
>
> What are these large circular 4-vane structures on the sides of [NOAA-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOAA-19) - the satellite that "fell down"?
>
> They remind me of adjustable air vents but I have a feeling that's not quite right.
>
> You can see them from [another angle here](http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewsr.html?pid=10299).
>
> [image]
>
> **Spacecraft rotated for better view:**
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Partial as i cannot currently find something that states "first":

But i note that:

Vanguard, Explorer, Pioneer, and previous Sputniks had passive thermal protection only (if any).

By May 1958, that leaves the Soviet Sputnik 3.

https://www.drewexmachina.com/2018/05/15/sputnik-3-the-first-orbiting-geophysical-laboratory/

> A fan circulated the internal nitrogen atmosphere of the satellite and 16 external louvers would open and close as needed to help maintain the internal temperature.

[image]

[image]

If Object D (same design as Sputnik 3, latter being the back up) had had a successful launch then it would have been the first in April 1958.

Comment: I am always amazed that the Soviets kept their electronics pressurized with a little fan to blow the air around and keep things cool. So typically Soviet! Simple, brute force, rugged.